# What is causing the erratic sine wave in my Hartley oscillator?

Tags: oscillator, output

I have made a Hartley oscillator in multisim in order to convert a DC input into an AC output but my output sine wave is not smooth. I don't know what is causing it.

Hartley oscillator configuration and component values:

[image]

Hartley oscillator AC output:

[image]

Comment: what is Zbe? relative to Rc

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 i am sorry but i am quite new to multisim but what is Zbe?

Comment: L1:L2 as 1:1 is quite a stiff ratio for a Hartley.

Comment: @Neil_UK thats perfect thank you so much I changed the ratio to 5:1 and it immediately fixed the issue. But why was the stiff ratio causing this problem do you know?

Comment: @ChristoPolachan You had too much feedback, so were overdriving the transistor.

Comment: Zbe or Rbe is the base resistance , when you add Re thus increases the base resistance. hFE*Re, reduces the base current and pulses the high Q filter for a longer duty cycle reducing the glitch as shown in my answer

Comment: Try putting a 220 ohm resistor in series with C3 to reduce the loop gain. The distortion should reduce.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this design is that Vbe gets turned off more than 50% of the cycle and that's when the signal current switches from the collector to the input reversing direction to the output.

When the collector voltage swings high it is already reducing in current and the Hartley inverts the phase 180 deg thru the "LCL" or "Pi" filter.

This effect can be reduced by reducing the current swing by adding a 150 Ohm from Q1-e thus raising the input impedance.

[Here's what I mean in simulation.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3AmArFaA2A7ATgBzK9gMwKSE44RoIgpKQBQALiMmuAjiIZACzueRwIALQ9oCMr0wIwCLGjKdhYcWiR0wGJGkjkcPNFnBx6Ady5JqYWRatsG5nIIQI%20YLNRd8HLV-xba-ghm4B6%20fKzhUCHcbjaEluA2weY8nGBsCXbRAE5cvEnUsSBpUFw6DABK%20XylxcRlgjyCKIJt0Ej0AOY1UcWRbfQA8lz6hSVocdSDADahVhzzUe1wEMIwkLJIGZuYpMg4mBj0c07%20Z16NsJuomwlwWEiP6q48GMcAxiBnsulhv1d4KsWNBCI9IApCGBIAdCNhvNcwPQAB7gJAYcB4cAYNw4FBuNgAGSRqJ4hGxfB02IxBJAhOCeWKmkyBUuglkJi%20WWxmUSbNu8AgMCwiDAPAQOjhZE0AkRMT5fn6fh8hEIbDFfCZPAi9C%20P0WpQBK3gLiBZrN5OECHQWjxdyc8gwmgFSPM3OsRTGHuiboKpUipQYeQDnEiRuM8HowcClzDi2cGBM5kilyV3l1UQB7gWAgFiBI5sL5JgOGIh2kiaQOET1ZdIUNBvS9ijvQ1rYw9jRKsSzPbzYADrZxu7tUJ081ye6wmlnIFnDgAPoIBeQBdkpCEFeI02JqHILebfdgBdIicleRlKiU7zGJcrk-IAwLwjQEU4LBw6s8LDiwyPA%20rPex5DAArow9Bnt%20bAXle4BUm0d48GukC4EuHRbseq7HgAagARgAphBpDnuqYSwQM2J3lhyAbgBmwAQgGAkImHZOiQaBgAk97Lpoz4LgAkgAOgAzgAFAAwvhACU9BkCwuYwBAYB0CAlT4SJikiSJjAAPYicpkAiTpAAWAC2wn0EAA)

[image]

Then with Re slider to near 0, Vbe is cutoff more than 2/3 of the time.

[image]

Thus the rapid turn-on pulse introduces a glitch into the otherwise high Q circuit.

Answer (score 0):

To make an oscillator to oscillate one must have an amp and feedback circuit which meet Barkhausen criteria - at certain frequency the total phase shift of the amp+feedback circuit is 0 or a multiple of 360 degrees and the amp amplifies at least as much as the feedback circuit attenuates. To get the oscillator to start the amp must amplify a little more than the feedback attenuates. Unfortunately the output amplitude grows until the amp distorts and that's also your case. Pure sine output needs an automatic gain limiting circuit (=AGC) which reduces the gain just to the exact balance with the feedback attenuation when the amplitude is good, but not too high causing distortion. Your oscillator hasn't such circuit. The amp distorts, it cannot output more.

LC circuit filters the result a little rounder than rectangular, but it's not sine, it has plenty of harmonic components. Math design of the circuit is needed to make the LC filtering so effective that the harmonic components are low enough without AGC circuit. An AGC circuit would make it work perfectly. It can make an oscillator to work so well that low distortion sine is possible even without LC filter, only RC phase shift feedback is needed.